# I keep getting an syntax error in python

Tags: python, indentation

```
temp =(input('Enter temperature to convert '))
if temp.endswith("C"):
    temp=temp[:-1]
temp_converted = (float(temp)-32)*(5/9)
print ('The converted temperature is', temp_converted, 'F')
else
    temp= temp[:-1]
tempnew=float(temp * (9/5) + 32)
print ('The converted tempature is', temp,'F')
```

I keep getting a syntax error at the else statement.

Comment: You can't insert other statements between if-else, plus a missing **`:`** after `else`.

Answer (score 0):

change it to `else:`

(colon at the end of else)

Comment: even after I add the colon I still get the message.

Comment: Yes, as others have pointed out you also need to fix the indentation so that the 'else:' block is followed by the 'if' block without any outdented lines in between.

Answer (score 0):

In python, leading white space is significant.  If you want the lines

```
temp_converted = (float(temp)-32)*(5/9)
print(...)
```

to be part of the true part of `if` statement, they need to line up with the previous line.  Also, all python control statements end in a `:`, including `else`, so overall, the code needs to look like

```
temp =(input('Enter temperature to convert '))
if temp.endswith("C"):
   temp=temp[:-1]
   temp_converted = (float(temp)-32)*(5/9)
   print ('The converted temperature is', temp_converted, 'F')
else:
   temp= temp[:-1]
tempnew=float(temp * (9/5) + 32)
print ('The converted tempature is', temp,'F')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp =(input('Enter temperature to convert '))
if temp.endswith("C"):
    temp=temp[:-1]
    temp_converted = (float(temp)-32)*(5/9)
    print ('The converted temperature is', temp_converted, 'F')
else:
    temp= temp[:-1]
    tempnew=float(temp * (9/5) + 32)
    print ('The converted tempature is', temp,'F')
```